# How to performance test Redshift Views?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, query-performance, sql-view

I have a question about testing query performance for views in redshift.

I have two tables: **table_a** and **table_b**:
 - table a and table b have different sort key defined.
 - table a has 6 fields for sort key.
 - table b has 4 fields for sort key.
 - both tables share some column names/types but table a is a super set of table b.

I created a view **v_combined**. The view combines data from table a and table b based on dates queried. For example if query is made before date XYZ, the view will source table a. Otherwise it sources table b.

```
create view as v_combined
select a as x, b as y, c as z, to_timestamp(time_field::TEXT, 'YYYYMMDD'):timestamp as date
from table_a
where date < "MY_DATE"

union all

select * from table_b
where date > "MY_DATE"
```

I did a comparison between the view and corresponding table:

1. `select count(*) from v_combined where date < "MY_DATE"`
2. `select count(*) from table_a where date < "MY_DATE"`
3. `select count(*) from v_combined where date > "MY_DATE"`
4. `select count(*) from table_b where date > "MY_DATE"`
5. `select * from v_combined where date < "MY_DATE" limit 10000`
6. `select * from table_a where date < "MY_DATE" limit 10000`
7. `select * from v_combined where date > "MY_DATE" limit 10000`
8. `select * from table_b where date > "MY_DATE" limit 10000`

(1) and (2) have similar execution time as expected.

(3) and (4) have similar execution time as expected.

(5) seems to have longer execution time than (6).

(7) seems to have longer execution time than (8).

What is the best way to test the performance of a view in redshift?

Comment: What does `"MYDATE"` represent? Is it normally a fixed date, but you have removed it from the question?

Comment: Hi John rotenstein, correct MY_DATE is a specific value I am using ... Yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that the best way to test the performance of a view is to run test queries exactly like you did!

The performance of this particular View will always be poor because it is doing a `UNION ALL`.

In (5), it needs to get ALL rows from both tables before applying the `LIMIT`, whereas (6) only needs to access `table_a` and can stop as soon as it hits the limit.

If you need good performance from queries like this, you could **consider creating a combined table** (rather than a view). Run a daily (or hourly?) script to recreate the table from the combined data. That way, queries will run much faster.

Comment: Thanks John. Interesting point that (5) needs to select ALL rows then apply limit while (6) stops after the limited number of rows.

Comment: What's the recommended way to create a combined table? Would this be a materialized table but still uses the union all query from above to create it?

Comment: Yes. Use whatever SQL you want to create it, but do it in one `SELECT` so that Redshift can store the data optimally. Base the `SORTKEY` and `DISTKEY` on the typical queries that will be run against it (`DISTKEY` = common `JOIN`, `SORTKEY` = common `WHERE`).

Comment: Thank you. Each day, table a and table b will get new data. Would this mean I'd need to drop and recreate the combined table each day? Combined, this will be about 500 billions of rows. I'm only afraid this drop/re-create may take a long time

Comment: Try it and see how long it takes, and see if the improved performance is worth the effort. You might be able to just append the new data to the table.